# A way to estimate whether a coin is biased based on the run of heads/tails parameter?

Tags: r, probability

QA

I have simulated the outcomes of a coin as H,T using the sample function

```
FlipCoin = function(n) sample(c("H", "T"), n, rep = T)
FlipCoin(23)
print(FlipCoin)
```

The O/P sequence is as follows
HHHTHTTTHHHHHTTTHTTTTHH

Q) B) 
Next i performed RLE function in R to arrive at the conclusion that the maximum run length encoding for the stimulated series was 5 .i. Mn = 5

```
R_L_E <- rle(FlipCoin(23))
R_L_E
```

O/P for RUN LENGTH ENCODING FOR "H"
HHH ,T, HTT THHHHHT TTHT TTTHH

3,1,5,1,2

Q(C)
For the next step I want to estimate the following.
For a sequence of length n = 786, we have observed a longest run of heads was equal to Mn = 11. Based on this piece of information, estimate whether the coin is fair?

I am looking for help on any formula or methodology to determine this. Also, I am doing this project in R and would appreciate help if can help me solving the last part (Part C) for the project.

Comment: As for methodology you might be looking for the runs test of Swed and Eisenhart (1943), [project Euclid link](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177731494) or for the Wald-Wolfowitz Test for Randomness, function [runs.test](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.7.9/topics/runs.test) in package `HwB`. My implementation of the SE test gives results similar to the latter.

Comment: @RuiBarradas from what i understand run tests are performed to estimate whether certain runs in a sequence are valid or not? However, here I don't knowthe simulation. The only info available is the length of the maximum run and I need to estimate whether it is a fair coin based on that sole information. My problem is exactly like the one below, but need help in understanding the solution.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2341170/assess-if-coin-is-fair-based-on-length-of-longest-run

Answer (score 4):

I am going to give some structure to this problem by taking $X_1,X_2,X_3,... \sim \text{IID Bern}(\theta)$ to be your observable sequence of coin flips.  Note that I have assumed exchangeability of the coin flips, which is a neccessary assumption for this kind of problem (which I will explain later).  Your statistical problem involves taking a sample of $n$ values and determining whether $\theta = \tfrac{1}{2}$ based on observation of the maximum length of a run of heads in the sample:

$$M_n \equiv \max_{1 \leqslant\ell \leqslant n} \sum_{i=\ell}^n \prod_{j = \ell}^{i} X_j.$$

The distribution of the maximum run-length for coin tosses is examined in [Schilling (1990)](https://www.csun.edu/%7Ehcmth031/tlroh.pdf).  Since you are interested in inference about a single parameter outcome against an alternative, this is a hypothesis testing problem where you null hypothesis is that the coin is fair.  I will show you how to perform a classical hypothesis test for the problem, but bear in mind that you could also apply a Bayesian test if you prefer.

This is a somewhat unusual problem, insofar as you do not observed the total number of heads and tails on the coin, so it is a non-standard runs test.  Essentially, it involves using the observed number of runs to make an inference about the likely number of heads in the sample, and then use this to infer whether or not the coin is fair.  (The intermediate inference is usually only implicit, since the test will go straight from the runs statistic to an inference of the fairness of the coin.)

---

**Classical hypothesis test:** Under the assumption of an exchangeable sequence of coin flips, it is possible to show that the statistic $M_n$ is stochastically increasing in $\theta$ ---i.e., a larger value of the parameter $\theta$ tends to make the values of $M_n$ larger.  (If we are unwilling to assume exchangeability then the parameter $\theta$ is not well-defined or identifiable, so this assumption is a necessity of the test.)  This is intuitively sensible, since a larger $\theta$ tends to give more heads, which tends to increase the largest run of heads.  To facilitate the test, we will denote the null distribution of this statistic as:

$$p_0(m) \equiv \mathbb{P}( M_n = m | \theta = \tfrac{1}{2}).$$

For a two-sided hypothesis test with $n$ data points, the p-value function is:

$$\text{p}(m_n) = \sum_{m=0}^n p_0(m) \cdot \mathbb{I}(p_0(m) \leqslant p_0(m_n)).$$

It is possible to derive the exact null distribution of the test statistic (see e.g., Schilling 1990, p. 198) or an asymptotic approximation (pp. 203-4).  In the present working I will approximate the null distribution by simulation.  Below we code the implementation of the test in `R` using $k=10^4$ simulations to approximate the mass function.  The graph at the end shows the simulated null distribution of the runs statistic, and the estimated p-value for the test with your data.  As you can see, the observed value is in the upper tail of the null distribution, and we obtain an estimated p-value of $\hat{\text{p}} = 0.044$ so there is some weak evidence to reject the null hypothesis that this is a fair coin.

```
#Define a function to calculate the runs for an input vector
RUNS_HEADS <- function(x) { n  <- length(x);
                            SS <- rep(0, n); WW <- rep(0, n);
                            for (l in 1:n) {  
                            for (i in l:n) { WW[i] <- prod(x[l:i]); }
                                             SS[l] <- sum(WW[l:n]); }
                            max(SS); }

#Set the data values
n <- 178;
R <- 11;

#Simulate the runs statistic for k permutations
k <- 10^4;
set.seed(936512074);
RR <- rep(0, k);
for (i in 1:k) { x_perm <- sample(c(0,1), n, replace = TRUE);
                 RR[i] <- RUNS_HEADS(x_perm); }

#Generate the frequency table for the simulated runs
FREQS <- as.data.frame(table(RR));

#Calculate the p-value of the runs test
R_FREQ <- FREQS$Freq[match(R, FREQS$RR)];
p      <- sum(FREQS$Freq*(FREQS$Freq <= R_FREQ))/k;

#Plot estimated distribution of runs with test
library(ggplot2);
ggplot(data = FREQS, aes(x = RR, y = Freq/k, fill = (Freq <= R_FREQ))) +
geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
geom_vline(xintercept = match(R, FREQS$RR)) +
scale_fill_manual(values = c('Grey', 'Red')) +
theme(legend.position = 'none') +
labs(title ='Runs Test - Plot of Distribution of Runs',
     subtitle = paste0('(Observed runs is black line, p-value = ', p, ')'),
     x = 'Runs', y = 'Estimated Probability');
```

[image]

If you wanted to go further than this, you could construct some simulations to estimate the power of the test for different values of $\theta \neq \tfrac{1}{2}$.  It is likely that the test would have low power, since the runs statistic is quite volatile.  The above result shows fairly weak evidence to reject the null hypothesis.  It is "statistically significant" at the $\alpha=0.05$ level, but not at lower levels.

Answer (score 2):

You might start thinking about the simple case of a "binomial experiment". If you have a fair coin and flip it 11 times, the probability of getting 11 heads in a row would be:

```
 0.5^11
#[1] 0.0004882812
```

So in something around 5 out of 10,000 tries of length 11, you should expect to all heads in a row. You observed a run in perhaps 775 attempts, under the null hypothesis of equal numbers of heads and tails, it might seem modestly unlikely to have observed such a long run. However, some simple simulation shows it's more common than that naive approach might suggest:

```
> rl <- rle( replicate(786, {rbinom(1,1,.5)}) )
> table( rl$lengths )

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
199 100  59  21  11   7   3   1
```

So that's a single run of a simulation. Let's run it a few more times:

```
> table(  rle( replicate(786, {rbinom(1,1,.5)}) )$lengths )

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12 
189  82  58  30   7   3   4   2   1   1   1   1 
> table(  rle( replicate(786, {rbinom(1,1,.5)}) )$lengths )

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  11 
178  97  62  23  15   2   2   3   1 
> table(  rle( replicate(786, {rbinom(1,1,.5)}) )$lengths )

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  10 
196  98  57  29  10   4   1   2   1 
> table(  rle( replicate(786, {rbinom(1,1,.5)}) )$lengths )

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7  11 
203  95  50  21  14   6   6   1 
> table(  rle( replicate(786, {rbinom(1,1,.5)}) )$lengths )

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7  10 
183 109  46  31   9   9   2   1 
> table(  rle( replicate(786, {rbinom(1,1,.5)}) )$lengths )

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
173 108  55  24  11   5   5   2 
> table(  rle( replicate(786, {rbinom(1,1,.5)}) )$lengths )

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  11 
160  89  54  32  12   8   1   4   1 
> table(  rle( replicate(786, {rbinom(1,1,.5)}) )$lengths )

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7  12 
204 100  50  19  14  10   2   1 
> table(  rle( replicate(786, {rbinom(1,1,.5)}) )$lengths )

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
184 115  55  20  10   8   3   1 
> table(  rle( replicate(786, {rbinom(1,1,.5)}) )$lengths )

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
201  85  60  24  12   7   3   2 
> table(  rle( replicate(786, {rbinom(1,1,.5)}) )$lengths )

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   9 
206 104  50  28  10   5   3   1 
> table(  rle( replicate(786, {rbinom(1,1,.5)}) )$lengths )

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  11 
188  89  56  26  13   2   5   2   1   1 
> table(  rle( replicate(786, {rbinom(1,1,.5)}) )$lengths )

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
211  97  60  27  10   2   1   3 
> table(  rle( replicate(786, {rbinom(1,1,.5)}) )$lengths )

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
197  87  49  28  19   4   3   2 
> table(  rle( replicate(786, {rbinom(1,1,.5)}) )$lengths )

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  10  12 
185  95  51  33   9   5   3   1   1   1
```

So it's really not that uncommon to see 10 or greater as the maximum run length. The number with heads is going to be one-half whatever estimate you get from this sort of simulation, since they would be equally distributed as heads or tails. Here's some further code that shows that 11 is a fairly common run length even in a sequence of that count:

```
m <- numeric(1000) 
for( i in 1:1000) { 
      m[i] <- as.numeric( names( tail(   # last column of the contingency table
                table(  rle( replicate(786, {rbinom(1,1,.5)}) )$lengths ) ,1) ) )}
> table(m)
m
  6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18 
  2  40 176 243 232 129  82  49  20  15   4   5   3
```

I suspect that the difference between what was predicted by the simplistic analysis and the simulation results may well be explained by a segment of statistical theory known as extreme value theory which studies the higher of  "order statistics", i.e the distribution of maxima and near maxima. The tails of the extreme value distributions tend to be longer than might be naively predicted based on Normal value theory.

Comment: From what I understood your answer pertains to simulating and calculating rle for different values, like a distribution. I however, require the opposite of it. I have a already set value of maximum rle in a distribution and need to find whether the coin used in simulation was fair or not? My question is exactly like the one in this below link. However, I couldn't understand the question and would appreciate if someone could help me understand it.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2341170/assess-if-coin-is-fair-based-on-length-of-longest-run

Comment: I thought you asked the question: "How likely is it that a fair coin would produce a maximal run length of heads that was 11 tries long?". That's what my simulation allows you to assess. I don't think you could have known ahead of time that the maximal length was 11.

Comment: In point of fact the second answer to the question cited : https://www.csun.edu/~hcmth031/tlroh.pdf and it nicely agrees with my concluding comments that a theoretic analysis would end up using extreme value statistics.

Comment: i am starting to understand what you meant and it does seem in the same vein. From what you answered I guess is to generate the discrete frequencies of the possible values, get the probabilities of all values and then check for hypothesis?

Comment: it is a hypothetical scenario. You know the maximum run of heads(is 11), for a simulation of coin toss (786 times). You have to assess whether it is fair coin based on it...From what i gather with your solution, it captures some value in m[i] for the ith iteration...those values form a discrete distribution and we need to calculate the prob of each possible value and check whether that falls within the CI to determine the hypothesis. One small doubt though, why is that 786 coin tosses return only 1 value? is it the rle of maximum number of heads for that one 786 coin toss simulation?

Comment: the question here is, say for one experiment of 786 coin tosses, you already know that the run of heads is 11, then estimate whether the coin is fair or not? Suppose I run your iteration only once, then I would get the rle value for that iteration in m...how can you tell from that value weather it is a fair coin or not?

Comment: The feature that is fixed is the number of items in the full sequence. The number 11 is NOT fixed. It is the result of one experiment. The question should be how likely is such a result. To answer that we perform 1000 similar experiments and see how likely it is to see such a long run (or longer).  That’s how to do frequentist statistics.